# How to split a string by Node Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, split

My array:

```
var str=['data1,data2 '];
```

I have used:

```
var arr = str.split(",");
```

But one error is showed. TypeError: Object data1,data2 has no method 'split'. How can I solve this problem.

My output will be:

```
arr= data1,data2
// or
arr[0]=data1;
arr[1]=data2;
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should do this :

```
var arr = str.toString().split(",");
```

"*TypeError: Object data1,data2 has no method 'split'*" indicates the variable is not considered as a string. Therefore, you must typecast it.

---

<sup>**update 08.10.2015**</sup> I have noticed someone think the above answer is a "*dirty workaround*" and surprisingly this comment is upvoted. In fact it is the exact opposite - using `str[0].split(",")` as 3 (!) other suggests is the real "dirty workaround". Why? Consider what would happen in these cases :

```
var str = [];
var str = ['data1,data2','data3,data4'];
var str = [someVariable];
```

`str[0].split(",")` will fail utterly as soon `str` holds an empty array, for some reason not is holding a `String.prototype` or will give an unsatisfactory result if `str` holds more than one string. Using `str[0].split(",")` blindly trusting that `str` always will hold 1 string exactly and never something else is bad practice. `toString()` is supported by numbers, arrays, objects, booleans, dates and even functions; `str[0].split()` has a huge potential of raising errors and stop further execution in the scope, and by that crashing the entire application.

If you really, really want to use `str[0].split()` then at least do some minimal type checking :

```
var arr;
if (typeof str[0] == 'string') {
    arr = str[0].split(',')
} else {
    arr = [];
}
```

Comment: Still, you count on the `.toString()` implementation of the array to always use `,` as its own delimeter. That is not set in stone. What if some future browser will decide to use newline character instead?

Comment: I mean that you assume `['data1,data2','data3,data4'].toString()` will return `'data1,data2,data3,data4'` - I don't think it's set  in stone. Best approach is joining it yourself i.e. `['data1,data2','data3,data4'].join(',')`

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Yes! Now I see what you mean, refering to `str = ['data1,data2','data3,data4']` - you are absolutely right! We cannot be sure browsers or **V8** in this case will return `data1,data2,data3,data4` in all future.

Answer (score 5):

If your starting point is a `array` with a `string` inside. This should work:

```
var arr = str[0].split(",");
```

Otherwise you should have a string as starting point for your code to work as you expected:

```
var str = 'data1,data2';
```

If you have more elements in the array you will need to iterate them with a for loop.

#### Edit to add other cases:

If you have several strings in that array, then you should be more carefull and do something like this:

```js
var str = ['data1,data2 ', ' data3, data4 ']; // notice these strings have many spaces in different places
var longString = str.join(',');
var array = longString.split(',').map(s => s.trim()).filter(Boolean); // removing spaces from start and end of strings, and eventually removing empty positions

console.log(array);
```

Comment: this should be the chosen answer. the current winner is just a dirty workaround that doesn't teach anything.

Comment: @Jonathan -  I do not consider `Array.toString()` as a "dirty workaround" at all. In fact it is the safe, secure way to do it. I think it is rather obvious why `str[0].split(",")` has the potential to crash the entire application. Have updated my answer to explain why.

Comment: @davidkonrad added a edit, to include cases of multiple strings inside that array.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, `str` is an array (with one element). If you want to split the string contained in the array, you have to *access* the array first:

```
var arr = str[0].split(",");
```

Answer (score -1):

let's say we have two date :

date1: 17/01/1989

date2:  20/02/2000

if we want to compare them just split the string and compare like this

```
var date1= date1.toString().split("/");

var date2= date2.toString().split("/");

var a = parseInt(date1[2] + date1[1] + date1[0]);

var b = parseInt(date2[2] + date2[1] + date2[0]);
```

if(a < b){

alert("date2 bigger than date1")}

}
 else if(a > b){

alert("date1 bigger than date2")

}
else{

alert("date 1 and date2 are equals ");

}